# Strange colors on question text

Tags: support, design

I'm having a really hard time reading questions because some letters seem to have blue or red... tendencies.

E.g.:

- tttttttttttt
- ffffffffffff
- oooooooooooo

They are really hurting my eyes. After 2-3 hours of reading questions, I see Ts and Fs and Os everywhere.

Is this an operating system bug or what? It is just me? It's the same in all browsers, at my office and at my home. I'm using Windows 7.

Edit:

I do believe it's because of the font, which is bolder for those letters:

[image: bold letters t, f and o]

Comment: Nope, don't see that. Could be your screens too..

Comment: Maybe a screeshot? **Edit:** Yup, it's defiantly your monitors, I don't see anything wrong with the screenshot your provided

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Update screenshot, it was black/white. Same thing Firefox, IE9, Chrome ...

Comment: Again, nothing. Sorry.

Comment: With regards to the screenshot, the colours are there. Take it into photoshop, zoom in and voila: http://i.imgur.com/37oqC.png

Comment: It's Cleartype, it uses colors at the edges to smoothen fonts.

Comment: _Nice_ work, @Bart.

Comment: I see it in the text of the post :/

Comment: I `<3` the new AMURRICA theme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you are using some kind of [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) which can cause blue and red fringing around the letter edges. The Windows version of that technique is called ClearType, try changing the settings for that or disable it entirely.

This is how the letters look for me (the o does not have any visible color fringing for me):

[image]

Comment: that is it, I've disabled it but now the text is too crowded or too bold. I still see colors in your screenshot.

Comment: @MihaiIorga, but how can you still see colors in his screen shot? You're rendering an image not a text anymore, I can't see the colors. That's strange.

Comment: I see colors. From my iPhone I don't, but from my work & hope PC I see them.

Comment: @dnan He can see the colours because they are there. Taking that image into Photoshop and zooming in reveals the following: http://i.imgur.com/37oqC.png So the colours are definitely there I would say.

Comment: So it hurts my eyes :)

Comment: @MihaiIorga The answer still remains valid though. This is a cleartype issue.

Comment: Alright, thanks for  clearing it Bart, that's great. But how can he see the colors in the image while I can't? Our browser/OS might be handling/rendering text differently, but I find it strange to happen also to images too.

Comment: @dnan That can have a variety of causes ranging from display quality to color profile calibration to the way your browser renders your jpegs and what not. For example, on my Android phone, the color shift is not nearly as apparent as on my calibrated monitor. And even there I seem to see a small different between Chrome and Internet Explorer. (Though I might have just gone loopy by staring at it for too long)

Comment: @Bart, excellent. Thanks Bart :D

Comment: It's all explained pretty well [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/).

Comment: @MihaiIorga: goog "cleartype tuning" + your OS version.

Comment: thank you, i hope I will get it right :)

Comment: I can see them too O_O